# HAProxy pgsql-check error

Tags: load-balancing, postgresql, haproxy

I use HAProxy 1.5-dev21 to load balance PostgreSQL connections over some read-only Postgresql 9.2 servers.

Version 1.5 of HAProxy implements a [pgsql-check option](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#option%20pgsql-check), similar to mysql-check.

Here is my typical HAProxy configuration for such pool:

```
listen pgsql_pool 0.0.0.0:10001
        mode tcp
        option pgsql-check user postgres
        balance roundrobin
        server slave1 10.0.0.1:5432 check
        server slave2 10.0.0.2:5432 check
```

That works, I mean HAProxy detects that slave1/slave2 are up and I can connect normally to PG on port 10001, but I see such messages in postgresql logs, every 2 seconds, due to pgsql-check option:

```
2014-01-29 17:37:33 CET [17170] postgres postgres (10.0.0.10(56706)) LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2014-01-29 17:37:35 CET [17173] postgres postgres (10.0.0.10(56707)) LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Maybe I am missing some configuration option somewhere?

Comment: What exactly do you want to fix (everything seems fine)?

Comment: So you think it´s a normal behaviour? This message means that the client (haproxy) did not closed the connection properly so I thought it may be related to a misconfiguration or a bug in haproxy pgsql check...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is really a problem. HAProxy documentation says that

> It is a basic but useful test which does not produce error nor
>   aborted connect on the server. This check is identical with the
>   "mysql-check.

Oh the other hand, mysql-check description is little more detailed:

> the check consists of sending two MySQL packet, one Client
>   Authentication packet, and one QUIT packet, to correctly close MySQL
>   session

Your log shows exactly this, so I don't think there is anything to worry about, but you might want to wait for pgsql experts or try at [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)